# Run jenkins job for merge request in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket server and Jenkins with bitbucket source plugin (declarative pipeline for multibranch).
How could I run specific stage only after merge request?

If use conditional when { changeRequest target: 'master' } - it works after pull requests, but when press button "merge" in Bitbucket - doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What branch you trigger the build ? you need to specify the exact branch you want to trigger

Have you configured  the jenkins job setting and bitbucket webhook settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, yep - I did every think for develop. I just find, that it possible via webhook (triggering different pipeline using token), but web hook doesn't return result to bitbucket.